# Odoo error Exception("Cannot update missing record %r" % xid)

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-12

helo i'm trying to modify a website footer in odoo12 without odoo's website builder
i got error :
Odoo Server Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 758, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 736, in _tag_template
    return self._tag_record(record, data_node)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 613, in _tag_record
    raise Exception("Cannot update missing record %r" % xid)
Exception: Cannot update missing record 'website.layout_footer'
```

also this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="website.layout_footer" inherit_id="website.footer_default">
            <xpath expr="//div[@id='connect']" position="replace">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top : 40px">

                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
                        <div class="widget">
                          <h5>Quick Navigation</h5>
                          <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Event</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Join US</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="widget">
                          <h5>Follow us</h5>
                          <ul class="company-social">
                              <li class="social-facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/samplelink/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                              <li class="social-vimeo"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/sample-company"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>  
                  </div>
              </xpath>
        </template>

    </data>
</odoo>
```

i got additional error too which seem have the same cause

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 966, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/api.py", line 759, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/api.py", line 746, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-61>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 445, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 561, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 421, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 222, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 68, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 802, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 865, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 755, in parse
    self.parse(rec, mode)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 764, in parse
    exc_info[2]
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 86, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 758, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 736, in _tag_template
    return self._tag_record(record, data_node)
  File "/media/renokurnia/8C2E74FE2E74E31E/Archives/Blue Print/RENODEV/odoo12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 613, in _tag_record
    raise Exception("Cannot update missing record %r" % xid)
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Cannot update missing record 'website.layout_footer'" while parsing None:4, near
<data inherit_id="website.footer_default">
            <xpath expr="//div[@id='connect']" position="replace">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top : 40px">

                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
                        <div class="widget">
                          <h5>Quick Navigation</h5>
                          <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Event</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Join US</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="widget">
                          <h5>Follow us</h5>
                          <ul class="company-social">
                              <li class="social-facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sample/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"/></a></li>
                              <li class="social-vimeo"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company-sample/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"/></a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>  
                  </div>
              </xpath>
        </data>
```

i have no experience costumizing website using odoo except from using odoo website builder, so i want to learn making module which can costumize website for my portofolio, please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need change id="website.layout_footer" by id="layout_footer".

If you doing this id="website.layout_footer". Odoo think you try to call and override the record layout_footer from module website. But layout_footer doesn't exist in website.